# Sorting multiple strings into an order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need an help on my php code

I got string array. It contains multiple values inside. Such as 'XXL', 'X', '1', '1.5','2', '3', 'T', '1K','1.5K','5K','Adult','One Size'.

Now I want it to be sorted as follows. 
2T, 3T, 4T, YXXS, YXS, YS, YM, YL, YXL, XXS, XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL, XXXL, WXXS, WXS, WS, WM, WL, WXL, WXXL, Youth, Adult, One Size, 8K, 8.5K, 9K, 9.5K, 10K, 10.5K, 11K, 11.5K 12K, 12.5K, 13K, 13.5K, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5, 15, Futsal

I need a sorting function or an algorithm to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `array_intersect` for this as there is really no logical way to sort these options.

```
<?php

$sort_order = array('2T', '3T', '4T', 'YXXS', 'YXS', 'YS', 'YM', 'YL', 'YXL', 'XXS', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'X', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL', 'WXXS', 'WXS', 'WS', 'WM', 'WL', 'WXL', 'WXXL', 'Youth', 'Adult', 'One Size', '8K', '8.5K', '9K', '9.5K', '10K', '10.5K', '11K', '11.5K 12K', '12.5K', '13K', '13.5K', '1', '1.5', '2', '2.5', '3', '3.5', '4', '4.5', '5', '5.5', '6', '6.5', '7', '7.5', '8', '8.5', '9', '9.5', '10', '10.5', '11', '11.5', '12', '12.5', '13', '13.5', '14', '14.5', '15', 'Futsal');
$sizes      = array('XXL', 'X', '1', '1.5','2', '3', 'T', '1K','1.5K','5K','Adult','One Size');

$sorted_sizes = array_intersect($sort_order, $sizes);

print_r($sorted_sizes);

?>
```